# Is it safe to dispose of a landing slip once I've left Hong Kong?

Tags: china, hong-kong, passport-stamps

Government information: http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/useful_information/non-stamping-immigration-clearance.html

As per normal procedures, I was given a Landing Slip while visiting Hong Kong (my suspicion being that it's because of Hong Kong's relationship with China).

I've since left Hong Kong, but I haven't yet returned to my home country, and will be visiting China later on in my trip.

Is it safe to dispose of my landing slip at this stage? If not, is it safe to do so once I return to my home country?

Comment: Didn't the government information you referred gave the answer? :)

Comment: @KH.Lee it says you shouldn't get rid of it before leaving, but doesn't explicitly say you can get rid of it afterwards.

Comment: See also: https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294217-i1496-k7991612-Hong_Kong_landing_slip_remain_in_passport-Hong_Kong.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you meant by China, is mainland China... I guess you better not throw it away. If some picky immigration officer will go scrutinize your travel history, you would have something to show for the period you spent on Hong Kong. If you don't have it that could be a red flag for them and I highly doubt they have immediate access to the database system of the Hong Kong Immigration Department.

BTW, the use of slip is not because of PRC-HKG relations but to save time. Source: http://www.scmp.com/news/hong-kong/article/1146055/immigration-department-end-visitor-passport-stamps . Apparently, you can ask the IO to stamp if you like. I wish I knew this so more stamps on my passport yay!